# How to use the camera calibration service in my app that uses artoolkit libs?

Tags: android, artoolkit

According to the documentation (https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_camera_calibration_service), I can use the calibration service by querying in their servers the camera parameters for the mobile which is launching my app with artoolkit libs but I didn't find the sample code that implements this calibration service. If someone could use the camera calibration service of artoolkit please let me know how you did it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to do anything it is already compiled into the ARToolKit libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how can I correct the distortion of the camera view in ArSimpleProj ? I thought it is due to a wrong calibration

Comment: Depends which mobile phone you are using and if ARToolKit-Server has a good calibration for that. You can calibrate your device yourself by using the ARToolKit camera calibration app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artoolworks.ar.utils.calib_camera

Comment: I did it, I used the calibration App of Artoolkit then I should see an improvement in my AR App but it doesn't reflect a change. I am using simpleArProj sample of ARToolkit. Maybe in this sample doesn't get the calibrated file from server, I don't know

Comment: Can you share an example of your output and your device details?